# Better way than multiple echo statements for printing a table?

Tags: php, html, performance

Is there any better way to do this code and dont ask why it's in echo's my brother did it that way not sure why but its slow i do want the echo

```
echo "<table id=\"vote\">";
echo "<th colspan=\"11\">Vote now!</th>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td><form action=\"vote.php?id=$id&value=\"0\"\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"value\" value=\"0%\" type=\"submit\"/></form></td>";
echo "<td><form action=\"vote.php?id=$id&value=\"10\"\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"value\" value=\"10%\" type=\"submit\"/></form></td>";
echo "<td><form action=\"vote.php?id=$id&value=\"20\"\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"value\" value=\"20%\" type=\"submit\"/></form></td>";
echo "<td><form action=\"vote.php?id=$id&value=\"30\"\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"value\" value=\"30%\" type=\"submit\"/></form></td>";
echo "<td><form action=\"vote.php?id=$id&value=\"40\"\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"value\" value=\"40%\" type=\"submit\"/></form></td>";
echo "<td><form action=\"vote.php?id=$id&value=\"50\"\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"value\" value=\"50%\" type=\"submit\"/></form></td>";
echo "<td><form action=\"vote.php?id=$id&value=\"60\"\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"value\" value=\"60%\" type=\"submit\"/></form></td>";
echo "<td><form action=\"vote.php?id=$id&value=\"70\"\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"value\" value=\"70%\" type=\"submit\"/></form></td>";
echo "<td><form action=\"vote.php?id=$id&value=\"80\"\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"value\" value=\"80%\" type=\"submit\"/></form></td>";
echo "<td><form action=\"vote.php?id=$id&value=\"90\"\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"value\" value=\"90%\" type=\"submit\"/></form></td>";
echo "<td><form action=\"vote.php?id=$id&value=\"100\"\" method=\"post\"><input name=\"value\" value=\"100%\" type=\"submit\"/></form></td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";
```

Comment: Put all that HTML in a PHP variable and then echo the variable itself?

Comment: What I meant was instead of echoing out single lines every time, just use echo once. Something like `echo $table` where `$table` will contain all the HTML + PHP

Comment: Because each echo involves an i/o transaction. Writing it to a variable does it all in memory with just one i/o at the end hense less i/o=better performance.

Comment: Yes Elpedro thats what i need better performance im running on localhost and it takes over 30secs to respond crazy.

Comment: 30 secs? That's way too much time for such a small piece of code. I'm starting to think the root problem is something else.

Comment: @ElPedro, You don't need a variable for that.  You know you can have string literals with multiple lines right?

Comment: @ElPedro: Usually PHP will buffer everything you echo until you call `flush` or the script ends.

Comment: Yeah but when i comment that section of code out it loads fast. i know i pull 3 seperate tables but still ive tested that.

Comment: @Brad & icktoofay - thanks. Was thinking more from the Javascript angle where performance can be massively improved by using a variable. Not a PHP expert so always happy to learn from those who know more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try a loop** (I took the liberty of changing one of the `echo` to use single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`) to get rid of all the escaping (`\`). I also replaced all your `echo` with a single variable (which sound be marginally faster).

```
$myForms = "";
$myForms .= "<table id=\"vote\">";
$myForms .= "<th colspan=\"11\">Vote now!</th>";
$myForms .= "<tr>";
for ($i = 0; $i < 110; $i += 10) {
    $myForms .= '<td><form action="vote.php?id=' . $id . '&value=' . $i . '" method="post">
                         <input name="value" value="' . $i . '%" type="submit"/>
                     </form>
                 </td>';
}
$myForms .= "</tr>";
$myForms .= "</table>";

echo $myForms;
```

Comment: somethings not right?  Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$i' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\admissions.php on line 94

Comment: 1 min i have to think for a min stressed ill reply in a min with your question

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest you seperate HTML and PHP code to make it easier to manage and using for loop to DRY your code:

```
<table id="vote">
<th colspan="11">Vote now!</th>";
<tr>
<?php
    for($i=0; $i <= 100; $i+=10) {
        <td><form action="vote.php?id=' . $id . '&value=' . $i . '" method="post"> <input name="value" value="' . $i . '%" type="submit"/> </form> </td>;
    }
?>
<tr>
</table>
```

Comment: 1 question im not goof with looping how would i delcare what cariable $i is ?    Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$i' (T_VARIABLE), expecting ';' in C:\xampp\htdocs\admissions.php on line 94

Comment: remove `int $i=0` by `$i = 0` and try again, `$i` here is just a variable and counter to run your for loop

Comment: @user1479606 In `vote.php?id=$id` you have to concatenate `$id`. Also, no `"` after `value=`.